# Cookie still exists in $_COOKIE array after using forget in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Before you mark this as a duplicate: **I'm aware of the other questions and the answers proposed there do not work for me**.

I am creating a cookie on login like this:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->withCookie(cookie('logged_in', true, 120));
}
```

I am trying to delete it on logout like this:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if(!auth()->check())
        return redirect('/');

    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $cookie = Cookie::forget('logged_in');

    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/')->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

But, after I log out, `dd($_COOKIE)` still shows the `logged_in` cookie in the array:

```
array (
  'logged_in' => 'eyJpdiI6IlA2NUlvWXdoaUZ4V2tzc0x5dDNibHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiK1lYWlwvSVJmaXNxNmowQ21ndG4wcVE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImQwMzdiM2I2ZjIxYjM3MzBjOWY5M2Y5NDQ0MDgxOTNlOGQ4ODYzMTc1MWE5NGY2NzY3Y2JhYWI1NmQyMjJhOTUifQ==',
  'XSRF-TOKEN' => 'eyJpdiI6IlZvbGRMVVRQTDlTSVhrZVFUQTdHRXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoielBtMHRSektnTzR5ZHBjY2xmNnA0akpyMXA3aWpRc0s2SFJUaHBJUzEzK3R3dzZNc1RqbUY0MG5FR0p5K3puZCIsIm1hYyI6IjMzN2Y0MDA3ZmYzM2VjZWU1OWFjYTgyMjVjZWQwNGQzNDdhN2ZiNjJlOWM0YWY0ZjkzYjM2NDc2NWI5ZjFhNzEifQ==',
  'staging_session' => 'eyJpdiI6IkEwS2YxeHZCK1doVWxHd2tNNStXR0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV2RScFYzQ2ZKTVwvblVLMDd5S0NKUWc5Z0JSUEZiOXF5Q3pkYktkMUQ0TE5MVWJ0cFgwOVBsMlR0TEhzMXZWWDQiLCJtYWMiOiI5MDdlMGU5Y2IyZTYyMzNjOTI4MWJmYTZmNDQwODc0ZjJhYmY1NjhmMzk4ZDhhMTIwYTQwYmVkNDVlZTc3ZDAyIn0=',
)
```

Both methods above are in `Auth\LoginController`.

This is one of the questions with a similar problem:

[Cookie::forget not working laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941672/cookieforget-not-working-laravel-5-1)

Neither of the two solutions presented there work for me (the one I used and the one using `Cookie::queue`).

EDIT: do read the exchange in the comments, it may be valuable.

Comment: _“after I log out, dd($_COOKIE) still shows …”_ - just to be clear, we are talking about a debug output _after_ a new request here, yes? (`$_COOKIE` does not get updated within the current script instance, if you add or remove cookies.) And it is not a caching problem either, if you reload the page you have that debug output on, it still stays the same?

Comment: @misorude Yes, when I reload the page, the output remains the same until the cookie naturally expires in 120 minutes.

Comment: Have you checked what the `Set-Cookie` response header actually contains (network panel in browser dev tools)? Is it set with correct values regarding domain and path (matching those the cookie was originally set with), and is the expires time in the past?

Comment: @misorude The domain and expiration are OK, but I see that httpOnly is checked for this cookie but not for some others (like the CSRF cookie). Could this be the issue? How do I remedy it if yes?

Comment: httpOnly specifies whether client-side JavaScript should have access to the cookie using `document.cookie` – but that in itself should not prevent it from being deleted via the proper HTTP Set-Cookie response header. Have you verified this is set in both cases, when the cookie gets originally created, and when you try to delete it? If it is not the same in both, that _could_ perhaps prevent things from working as expected.

Comment: @misorude When I login, I see the cookie in the header. When I log out, it's not there.

Comment: Which request exactly are you looking at here now, considering there also seems to be a HTTP redirect involved?

Comment: @misorude For login, I'm looking at the POST request to /login; for logout, I was looking at the wrong thing, sorry. When I look at the logout request, the logged_in cookie header is still there.

Comment: Not sure whether you are correctly differentiating between _response_ headers (Set-Cookie, to set or delete a cookie), and _request_ headers (Cookie, which sends existing cookies back to the server) now …? A `Set-Cookie` header of course needs to be present in the response, if you want to _remove_ the existing cookie.

Comment: @misorude I am looking under Network -> Response Headers -> Set Cookie ... that's the correct place as far as I can tell. So, to confirm, both on login and logout, the logged_in cookie is there.

Comment: The Set-Cookie _has_ to be there, to delete the cookie. But it has to contain the correct values, to actually delete the already existing cookie. Apart from the value, the rest should match what was used when the cookie was created (and expiration in the past.)

Comment: @misorude This is the whole thing on logout: `Set-Cookie: logged_in=eyJpdiI6ImllQXJiNEVNMEhjaWxDQnB5UnNLcWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRnJ2QmRCMlo4cEp6N00rQ1FsMVwvc2c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjA3YTJhY2JlYzQ5MmU4NjQ4ODQ5YTZmZGE5NDdhZGM0NjFjMTZmYmUxYzY3ZTRlNGVlMDIxMmJhZWMxOWU2OTAifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 05-Feb-2016 12:06:45 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly`